# Database data not showing correctly in Php using PDP

Tags: php, mysql

First I could display all my categories from the database, then I did the same code to display the brands but when I run the page it prints as you can see in the image:

[image]

My table looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="product_name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Brand</td>
            <td>  
                <select name="" id="">
                    <optgroup label="Select a Brand"></optgroup>
                        <?php 
                        global $conn;
                        try{
                            //prepare statement
                            $statement=$conn->prepare('select * from brands');
                            //bind statement parameters
                            $statement->bindParam(':brand_id', $brand_id);
                            $statement->bindParam(':brand_name', $brand_name);
                            //execute statement
                            $statement->execute();

                            while($result=$statement->fetch()){
                                $brand_id = $result['brand_id'];
                                $brand_name = $result['brand_name'];

                                echo "<option value=".$brand_id.">" .$brand_name. "</option>";
                            }
                        }
                        catch(PDOException $e){
                            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                        }
                        $conn = null;
                    ?>          
                </select> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Category  </td>
            <td>  
                <select name="" id="">
                    <optgroup label="Select a Category"></optgroup>
                        <?php           
                            global $conn;
                            try{                                    
                                //prepared statement
                                $statement = $conn->prepare('select * from categories');
                                //bind parametes
                                $statement->bindParam(':category_id', $category_id);
                                $statement->bindParam(':category_name', $category_name);
                                //execute
                                $statement->execute();
                                //set the result

                                while($result=$statement->fetch()){
                                    $category_id = $result['category_id'];
                                    $category_name = $result['category_name'];
                                    echo "<option value=".$category_id.">" .$category_name. "</option>";
                                }   
                            }
                            catch(PDOException $e){
                                echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                            }
                            $conn = null;
                        ?>                          
                </select> 

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Image</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="product_image"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Description</td>
            <td><textarea name="product_description" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Price</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="product_price"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="submit_row" align="center">
            <td class="submit_row" align="center">
                <input type="submit" name="submit-button">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

For some reason, I can only get the brands and not the categories, plus I cannot see the rest of the fields.

I hope you can help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you binding in `$statement->bindParam` ??? You have no parameters to bind Too

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: No error message

Comment: When I had it done for the categories it was working, only when I added for brands it broke the html structure and did not show the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are destroying your connection when you run this line

```
$conn = null;
```

after completing your `brands` selection and before starting your `categories` selection. you dont need to destroy the connection, instead let PHP do that automatically when your script exits.

Also as you dont have any parameters in your query you dont need either of the `bindParam` calls

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="product_name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Brand</td>
            <td>  
                <select name="" id="">
                    <optgroup label="Select a Brand"></optgroup>
                        <?php 
                        global $conn;
                        try{
                            //prepare statement
                            $statement=$conn->prepare('select * from brands');
                            //execute statement
                            $statement->execute();

                            while($result=$statement->fetch()){
                                $brand_id = $result['brand_id'];
                                $brand_name = $result['brand_name'];

                                echo "<option value=".$brand_id.">" .$brand_name. "</option>";
                            }
                        }
                        catch(PDOException $e){
                            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                        }
    // delete the collowing line
                        //$conn = null;
                    ?>          
                </select> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Category  </td>
            <td>  
                <select name="" id="">
                    <optgroup label="Select a Category"></optgroup>
                        <?php           
                            global $conn;
                            try{                                    
                                //prepared statement
                                $statement = $conn->prepare('select * from categories');
                                //execute
                                $statement->execute();
                                //set the result

                                while($result=$statement->fetch()){
                                    $category_id = $result['category_id'];
                                    $category_name = $result['category_name'];
                                    echo "<option value=".$category_id.">" .$category_name. "</option>";
                                }   
                            }
                            catch(PDOException $e){
                                echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                            }
    // delete the collowing line
                            //$conn = null;
                        ?>                          
                </select> 

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Image</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="product_image"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Description</td>
            <td><textarea name="product_description" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Price</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="product_price"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="submit_row" align="center">
            <td class="submit_row" align="center">
                <input type="submit" name="submit-button">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So in summary I was destroying my database connection and also did not know that bindParam is only used when I have parameters in the query.
Appreciate the support